# The application crashes in the APK file but does not crash in emulators

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I created a project in LibGdx. The program launches and works perfectly both in Android Studio emulators and on real devices. When I tried to publish the application on Google Play, Google refused and replied that the application was loading but crashing. And sends a screenshot.
[image]

[image]

I created a signed APK file and launched it in the BlueStacks program. To my surprise, the program actually crashes. I found exactly where the application crashes. When loading assets, I load skins of my images:

```
SkinLoader.SkinParameter param_dialogs = new SkinLoader.SkinParameter(
            "dialogs/dialogs.atlas");
assetMan.load("dialogs/dialogs.json", Skin.class, param_dialogs);
```

It is this code that causes the application from the APK file to crash. But this code does not crash when I run the application from Android Studio in emulators and real devices.
What am I doing wrong? Maybe I'm loading skins into assets incorrectly?

**I solved the problem by transferring the project to gdx-liftoff. Downloaded from https://github.com/tommyettinger/gdx-liftoff **

Comment: For future reference, make sure you upload your proguard mapping file to your release in Google Play. Then if it crashes during their testing, you can go in and look at the stack trace. Or if you use app bundles instead of APKs, this is already included automatically. Your crash in this case is probably because of the Proguard configuration not set up to ignore obfuscation of some of the Skin-related classes. Make sure you always test a production build locally before uploading to Google Play. You can change whether Android Studio is building debug or production builds when you click Run.

Answer (score -1):

**Try to surround the code with try/catch block and log the error, to show what's the problem**

```
try {
    SkinLoader.SkinParameter param_dialogs = new SkinLoader.SkinParameter(
    "dialogs/dialogs.atlas");

    assetMan.load("dialogs/dialogs.json", Skin.class, param_dialogs);
} catch (Exception exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, exception.getMessage());
}
```